# Problemas en update laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Amigos tengo problemas al actualizar un registro laravel cuando selecciono todo de la Subserie me trae lo subiente

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:19 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "serie_id" => 1
    "nombreSubSeries" => "Planes de Negocio"
    "codigoSubSeries" => "852"
    "originalSubSeries" => null
    "copiaSubSeries" => null
    "soporteSubSeries" => "1"
    "gestionSubSeries" => "0"
    "centralSubSeries" => "2"
    "ctfisicoSubSeries" => null
    "ctelectronicoSubSeries" => "1"
    "microfilmacionSubSeries" => null
    "digitalizacionSubSeries" => "1"
    "seleccionSubSeries" => "1"
    "eliminacionSubSeries" => null
    "estado" => "2"
    "created_at" => "2018-09-05 19:24:56"
    "updated_at" => "2018-09-05 19:24:56"
    "deleted_at" => null
  ]
  1 => array:19 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "serie_id" => 2
    "nombreSubSeries" => "peticiones, quejas y reclamos"
    "codigoSubSeries" => "852"
    "originalSubSeries" => null
    "copiaSubSeries" => null
    "soporteSubSeries" => "1"
    "gestionSubSeries" => "0"
    "centralSubSeries" => "3"
    "ctfisicoSubSeries" => null
    "ctelectronicoSubSeries" => null
    "microfilmacionSubSeries" => null
    "digitalizacionSubSeries" => "1"
    "seleccionSubSeries" => "1"
    "eliminacionSubSeries" => null
    "estado" => "2"
    "created_at" => "2018-09-05 19:27:24"
    "updated_at" => "2018-09-05 19:27:24"
    "deleted_at" => null
  ]
]
```

pero cuando filtro por id sale nulo generando el suguiente error

> "Creating default object from empty value"

Este es mi codigo

```
    $Subseries = SubSeries::find($id);
    /*$Subseries = SubSeries::all()->toArray();*/
    /*dd($Subseries);*/
    $Subseries->serie_id = $request->get('serie_id');
    $Subseries->nombreSubSeries = $request->get('nombreSubSeries');
    $Subseries->codigoSubSeries = $request->get('codigoSubSeries');
    $Subseries->originalSubSeries = $request->get('originalSubSeries');
    $Subseries->copiaSubSeries = $request->get('copiaSubSeries');
    $Subseries->soporteSubSeries = $request->get('soporteSubSeries');
    $Subseries->gestionSubSeries = $request->get('gestionSubSeries');
    $Subseries->centralSubSeries = $request->get('centralSubSeries');
    $Subseries->ctfisicoSubSeries = $request->get('ctfisicoSubSeries');
    $Subseries->ctelectronicoSubSeries = $request->get('ctelectronicoSubSeries');
    $Subseries->microfilmacionSubSeries = $request->get('microfilmacionSubSeries');
    $Subseries->digitalizacionSubSeries = $request->get('digitalizacionSubSeries');
    $Subseries->seleccionSubSeries = $request->get('seleccionSubSeries');
    $Subseries->eliminacionSubSeries = $request->get('eliminacionSubSeries');
    $Subseries->estado = $estado;
    $Subseries->save();
```

Comment: Te sugiero que acomodes tu código para así poderte ayudar..

Comment: El error dice que no esta trayendo el registro de la bd, por lo cual comprueba la primarykey de tu modelo `SubSeries` que sea igual a la de tu tabla, ademas podrías agregar el modelo a la pregunta para tener mas informacion

Comment: Seguramente tu id no está llegando con el valor que estás esperando, imprime el valor y checa que coincida con el valor de tu registro ya que te está trayendo un resultado vacío.

Answer (score 0):

amigo estas recibiendo un array primero debes recorrerlo con un foreach y luego debes a cada item sacarle el valor que necesitas como `item[0]-> serie_id`

Comment: Esta respuesta fue reportada como de baja calidad porque parece mas un comentario que una respuesta. Podrias elaborarla un poco mas?

Answer (score 0):

Primero asegura que el modelo **SubSeries** tenga definida la propiedad

```
protected $fillable = ['nombreSubSeries', 'codigoSubSeries','...demas campos',];
```

Luego en el controlador así debería quedar tu método `update`

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
    $Subseries = SubSeries::findOrFail($id);
    if($Subseries->update($request->all())
    {
      //mensaje de actualizado correctamente y demás acciones al actualizar
    }else{
      //mensaje error de no actualizado
    }
}
```